# Wireless Adhoc between virtual guests

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, adhoc

I am trying to simulate an wireless adhoc networking environment.

Thus, I have come up with an idea of using virtual guests (in VirtualBox) as the mobile nodes, and those nodes can communicate with each other in an adhoc manner while they are operating.

I have searched among many other sites about how to do the adhoc networking between the virtual guests. But, it seems that I found nothing relevant.

Therefore, I would like to ask anyone for help on this problem. Please let me know, should you have any ideas or solutions regarding the Adhoc networking among virtual guests?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are trying is not *simulating* an ad hoc network, but *emulating* the network.
You need to simulate the physical layer between them, so packets are dropped based on for example the distance between the, the amount interference and noise, the type modulation, coding etc. This is complicated and I suggest you use existing software instead of creating your own.

Check out EstiNet:
http://www.estinet.com/products.php
or its free older version NCTUns:
http://nsl10.csie.nctu.edu.tw/

For actual simulation check this:
http://www.nsnam.org/, which also support emulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.... I might get confused with the terms of emulation and simulation. anyway, the point i'm trying to say is that i'm trying to simulate/emulate the DTN with adhoc networking. I have also tried with NS2 simulator, but it is hard to find the right DTN for NS2 simulator. That's why i want to get DTN installed on Virtual guests and test with Adhoc networking between the guests...

Comment: I understood that part. But you need something to simulate the wireless channel, and the connectivity between the guests, and thats what you need an emulator for. The simulate wireless channel would drop a certain amount packets, when the virtual guests are within simulated range. Virtual guests is not a bad approach, it allows you to test real applications, you need to simulate both the movement of the guests, and the wireless channel. I am working on a DTN emulator myself, using virtual devices like you, but based on The ONE simulator, but it will not be ready until a couple of months.

Comment: That would be a big help to know that you are working on a DTN based on The ONE simulator, since I'm really new to those things. Would you mind telling me about what The ONE simulator is like? and possibly, how you would emulate your DTN?